# what is the real CPU limit for virtual machines in a subscription

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

The **vCPU limit per subscription is 20** (according to this page: [Azure Subscription Limits Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)).

However, when following this other page, [Azure VM Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quotas), and get-azurermvmusage command is used it **shows that the limit for Total Regional vCPUs is 350**.

This latter page says:

> The vCPU quotas for virtual machines and virtual machine scale sets
>   are arranged in two tiers for each subscription, in each region. The
>   first tier is the Total Regional vCPUs, and the second tier is the
>   various VM size family cores such as the D-series vCPUs. Any time a
>   new VM is deployed the vCPUs for the VM must not exceed the vCPU quota
>   for the VM size family or the total regional vCPU quota. If either of
>   those quotas are exceeded, the VM deployment will not be allowed.
>   There is also a quota for the overall number of virtual machines in
>   the region.

**How do these two limits work together:**
**-> is 20 a soft limit and 350 a hard (maximum) for the that region?**

Answer (score 2):

soft limit is the default you get when you provision a subscription, hard limit is what you can get if you raise a support request and request to raise the limit ( you dont necessary get to the limit in one support request ). you cannot go beyond hard limit (to my knowledge).